# Continuity Function Problem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose f(x) is a continuous function from [0,1] into [0,1]. Show that there exists a point $\xi \in [0,1]$ such that $f(\xi) = \xi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x) = x - f(x) $. Notice

$$ g(0) = 0 - f(0) = -f(0) <0 $$
Similarly,
$$ g(1) = 1 - f(1) > 0 $$

Hence, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $\xi \in [0,1]$ such that $g( \xi ) = \xi - f( \xi ) = 0 \implies f(\xi ) = \xi $

Comment: just a small conceptual thing, does ivt allows $\geq$ or must it be strictly >? Cos from what I see it can be = 0, not necessarily >0

Comment: In general this argument works as long as the image interval is entirely within the domain interval right?

Comment: that is right..